# How to determine whether a data set is continuously growing?

Tags: regression, sampling, curve-fitting

I sampled some data at certain sampling rate (e.g., 1 sample per minute). I want to know whether the values in this data set are continuously growing or they are just fluctuating around certain value. How can I do that?

In addition, I would like to predict the future values to be sampled. Based on the prediction (whether it will grow along with certain confidence level), I can decide whether to continue the experiment to sample more data or simply stop the experiment.

**Update**: I think this is exactly what I need: [Trend Esitmation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trend_estimation)

**Note:** I know very little (if not nothing) about statistics, so bear with me and do correct me if you find me using wrong terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to regress on time. What software are you using?

This is a very simple approach that doesn't allow for effects other than a continuous effect of time. In R you could do something like this.

```
time <- 1:10
values <- c(2,4,5,7,5,6,8,10,11,10)
m1 <- lm(values~time)
summary(m1)
```

but you will probably have more values (and times) and you may be reading from some other file, which would change things.

summary(m1) yields

> Call: lm(formula = values ~ time)

This just says what m1 is.

> Residuals:
>       Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
>   -1.3455 -0.8455  0.1091  0.8136  1.5636

This gives some info about the residuals. You can get more with plot(m1). Ordinary least square regression assumes some things, including that the residuals are normally distributed with constant variance.

> Coefficients:
>
> Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
>
> (Intercept)   1.8000     0.7412   2.428   0.0413 *
>
> time          0.9091     0.1195   7.610 6.25e-05 ***

this tells you the model that is estimated by m1: value = 1.8 + .91*time. It also give the standard errors of the coefficients (0.74 and 0.12), their t-values and their statistical significance.

> Residual standard error: 1.085 on 8 degrees of freedom Multiple
>   R-squared: 0.8786,     Adjusted R-squared: 0.8635  F-statistic: 57.92
>   on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 6.245e-05

If you want to do more complex things, let us know more about your problem.

Comment: I'm using R as well, but I'm open to any software. Problem is I don't understand at all the output of `summary(m1)`. Can you explain that to me, or you can point me to some references?

Comment: Well, the easiest way to get *some* help is ?lm while in R. But that's not necessarily the easiest help to read. :-).  I will edit my answer.

Comment: I would also like to suggest using `plot(time, values, type="b")` to visualize the temporal trend of the outcome.

Comment: Thanks for the details! But I still don't know which numbers to look at. When the data set is almost linear, it makes sense to look at the intercept value (.91 in the example). But what if it fluctuates? Like `values <- c(5, 7, 3, 4, 6, 5, 8, 2, 6, 4)`?

Comment: No, the intercept is not interesting in most cases. You want to look at the parameter for time.  If the data fluctuates then it doesn't grow continuously.

Comment: @PeterFlom What specific parameters of time should I look at to determine whether the data fluctuates?

Comment: There is only one parameter associated with time in the model I showed. You don't need a parameter to know if the data fluctuates - it does.  I think what you want is to determine if the trend is "big" compared to the fluctuation.

Comment: @PeterFlom I see what you are saying. I played with R a bit, and understood the coefficient of time is the key. Now, how can we compare the coefficient with the degree of fluctuation?

Comment: @PeterFlom If I'm only interested in the overall trend, is it enough to look at the correlation between `values` and `time`: `cor(x=values, y=time)`?

Comment: @dacongy Correlation will tell you how *consistently* the values change over time.  The slope/coefficient/"parameter" for time tells you how *much* they change per unit of time.  The *t*-statistic and *p*-value associated with that slope tells you something about how statistically significant it is--how rare such a slope would be if it were the result of chance alone (and if the slope in the larger population were zero).

Comment: Statistical models are designed to separate signal (the model) from noise (the fluctuation). So, the F test compares these two.

Answer (score 1):

The idea that Trend Estimation might be appropriate is in the right direction but very very far from the answer. In practice one doesn't know how many trends there or the length of the (each) trend , in fact one wants to discover them. One doesn't know if there are level/step shifts and how many and the length of each step. Step shifts are intercept changes which can confuse trend detection schemes which is why you need to find procedures which suggest both kinds. Distinguishing between Outliers and Inliers is an important consideration in trend/level detection. If the observed series is auto-correlated then this often masks or falsely suggests trend/level structure. One has to integrate ARIMA memory and Intervention Detection procedures to answer the question about trends and steps. Fitting splines is rather useless as one doesn't know how many local splines there are and the length of the spline . Now not to further complicate this already complicated answer error variance change or ARIMA model parameters may change over time causing both false negatives and false positives with respect to trend/steps. The solution is to implement software that deals with all of these possible states of nature and parsimoniously delivers a uselful model with useful conclusions regarding trends/steps.pulses and seasonal pulses. See http://www.unc.edu/~jbhill/tsay.pdf for a discussion.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the big picture. I have some follow-up questions: (1) Are there well-accepted software tools that do trend estimation? (2) Is there any existing approach that produces good results when the input data set is from specific domain , and has relatively predictable pattern? (3) Can we tune the parameters to have a detection that is biased toward level? In other words, when it says level, it is definitely level; but when it says trend, the reality may or may not be trend (i.e., it can be level).

Comment: I understand your first question means softare that "finds the unspecified determinstic structure" . AUTOBOX a product that I am involved with as a developer (http://www.autobox.com) is one. A second is SAS and a third is SPSS. I don't understand your second question. AUTOBOX allows the user to specify alpha levels (probability levels) to guide selection of trend vs step. For example one could set .05 for steps and .10 for trends , tilting

Comment: AUTOBOX allows the user to specify alpha levels (probability levels) to guide selection of trend vs step. For example one could set .10 for steps/levels and .05 for trends , tilting the software's preference for steps/levels.